# Can't get Tortoise SVN to use SSH correctly

Tags: tortoisesvn, phabricator

I am using Phabricator to host a Subversion repository. It is currently empty prior to importing from an older repository.

Here is what I have done so far:

- Generate a keypair using puttygen and saved it.
- Exported same keypair to OpenSSH format and saved it to $HOME/.ssh/svn.key in my MSys2 environment.
- Set up $HOME/.ssh/config to have an entry for my host in my MSys2 environment.
- Put my public key into Phabricator.
- Used MSys2 environment to perform `svn list` command on the repository. **This worked.**
- Used PuTTY to set up a session with pre-configured hostname, port, username and private key (the one generated earlier).
- Used PuTTY to open the session above. **This worked. I disabled automatically closing the window and the text displayed was the same as when I SSH in on the command line in my MSys2 environment.**
- Set TortoisePLink.exe explicitly in the TortoiseSVN->Settings->Network dialog.
- Used TortoiseSVn to browse the repository using a URL of the form `svn+ssh://<PuTTY session name>/<repo path>` where the repo path is exactly the same as when using MSys2.

The last step doesn't work. The TortoiseSVn repo browser pauses for a modest delay and then reports "Network connection closed unexpectedly".

I know the PuTTY session is being used because if I remove the username from the session config, TortoiseSVN asks me for the username to use.

---

I have just found that if I retry the same URL a second time, it succeeds.

I have upgraded to TortoiseSVN1.10 and it makes no difference.

---

I ran the SSH daemon in debug mode and near the end of the log I see:

```
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 113
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 113
debug3: mm_answer_audit_command entering
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 11 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: send packet: type 99
debug2: channel 0: read 13 from efd 11
debug2: channel 0: rwin 2147483647 elen 13 euse 1
debug2: channel 0: sent ext data 13
debug2: channel 0: read 11 from efd 11
debug2: channel 0: rwin 2147483634 elen 11 euse 1
debug2: channel 0: sent ext data 11
Connection closed by 192.168.0.101 port 52769
```

Everything looks fine up to this point. 192.168.0.101 is my TortoiseSVN machine. I wish I could somehow see what TortoiseSVN is saying and what the SVN server is replying.

Comment: Try this and see if this works: Open up your **TortoiseSVN Settings** > **Network** pane. Then in the SSH Client field try using this: 
`"C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoisePlink.exe" -l "<path to private key>.ppk"`

Comment: I did that, also removing the private key from the PuTTY configuration to avoid a clash. Now I get a popup that says "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)". I don't think this is the right track since a raw PuTTY connection works fine.

Comment: I thought my problem might be because I had two SSH sessions for Phabricator, one for Subversion on port 2222 and an admin one for normal SSH on port 22. However deleting the normal one didn’t help.

Comment: I got TortoisePlink to work by using the most basic URL and specifying the key, username, and port as options. However browsing the repo still doesn't work.

Comment: It currently looks like a Phabricator bug. Using TortoisePlink I reproduced an SVN conversation that I sniffed when connecting to my old non-SSH repo, and got an exception from Phabricator.